# Flag usage for multibranch logic

Tags: python, enums, flags

I need to do something like this:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class WISENESS(Flag):
    Y = auto()
    M = auto()
    D = auto()
    YM = Y | M
    YD = Y | D
    MD = M | D
    YMD = Y | M | D

first_case = WISENESS.Y

first_case == WISENESS.Y # True
first_case == WISENESS.M # False
first_case == WISENESS.D # False

###

second_case = WISENESS.YD

second_case == WISENESS.Y # True
second_case == WISENESS.M # False
second_case == WISENESS.D # True

####

third_case = WISENESS.YMD

third_case == WISENESS.Y # True
third_case == WISENESS.M # True
third_case == WISENESS.D # True
```

I.e. depending on the flag value it will be true in some cases. For example, I may need to perform an operation for all possible cases, or only for two of them.
Like this example here:

```
if WISENESS.Y:
    do_something_in_case_of_Y_or_MY_or_YD_or_YMD()
if WISENESS.M:
    do_something_in_case_of_M_or_MD_or_YM_or_YMD()
if WISENESS.D:
    do_something_in_case_of_D_or_MD_or_YD_or_YMD()
```

I tried to use Flag from the enum module in the standard library, guessing it could help me in this case, but either I don't understand how it works, or I must achieve my goal in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in way to check for `Flag` membership is with the standard Python `in` operator:

```
>>> second_case in WISENESS.Y
True
```

and your final example would be:

```
some_flag = ...

if WISENESS.Y in some_flag:
    do_something_in_case_of_Y_or_MY_or_YD_or_YMD()
if WISENESS.M in some flag:
    do_something_in_case_of_M_or_MD_or_YM_or_YMD()
if WISENESS.D in some flag:
    do_something_in_case_of_D_or_MD_or_YD_or_YMD()
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: See Ethan Furman's answer for the proper Pythonic approach to this problem. This answer explains how to check for flag inclusion with bitwise operators, which are useful in other situations and other programming languages.

To check for flag inclusion in a value, you should use bitwise operators, specifically `&`.

```
wiseness = WISENESS.MD
if wiseness & WISENESS.Y == WISENESS.Y:
    print('contains Y')
if wiseness & WISENESS.M == WISENESS.M:
    print('contains M')
if wiseness & WISENESS.D == WISENESS.D:
    print('contains D')
```

The `&` AND operator works by returning which bits are the same in the two supplied values. In your enum definition, `auto()` supplies the values `Y = 1`, `M = 2`, `D = 4`, which in binary are `0001`, `0010`, and `0100` respectively. The combination values then contain a bit from each flag they contain, formed by the `|` OR operator, for example `MD = 0010 | 0100 = 0110`.

In the above code then, where `wiseness` is `0110`, the following `&` checks are made:

```
wiseness & WISENESS.Y --> 0110 & 0001 = 0000 --> != WISENESS.Y
wiseness & WISENESS.M --> 0110 & 0010 = 0010 --> == WISENESS.M
wiseness & WISENESS.D --> 0110 & 0100 = 0100 --> == WISENESS.D
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer provided. I will check it tomorrow and mark it as an answer, in case it works.

Comment: You have provided a great example good sir. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Bit-wise operators are not the best way to do this check; also, your last examples are not valid Python.

Comment: @EthanFurman The second code block is not Python, it's just an example of the math being done. I did not know you could use `in` for `Flag` enums though, that's neat.

Comment: Ah.  I reformatted that block so I could remove my down-vote (and hopefully make it more clear).